# Postgres says Unable to find database "projectClosure"

Tags: database, postgresql, alter, postgresql-9.4

Just to give background of the story, I'm using `Postgres 9.4` and  have created a database/schema with name `projectClosure` using tool PGAdmin.
I am able to see the created database in PGAdmin's Object Browser, connect to it and also create objects (tables) in the database, However when I'm trying to execute sql

```
ALTER DATABASE projectClosure
  SET bytea_output = 'escape';
```

I get error saying the database does not exist.
To make sure I'm not making mistake while creating database, I tried creating several other database instances with dummy names, for these databases the above mentioned query works fine (of cource after changing the database name).
Can someone point out what I'm doing wrong.
Is `projectClosure` some reserved keyword in Postgres?

> screenshots
>   1. `projectClosure` error[image]
>   2. success for `abc` database [image]

PS : I think this is weird.

Comment: `ALTER DATABASE "projectClosure"`: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-IDENTIFIERS

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name what am I looking for in the link?

Comment: The explanation why `"projectClosure"` is something different then `projectClosure`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name :  thanks a lot, I wouldn't have figured it out even after wasting too much time. Would you mind posting it as an answer so that it will be helpful for others like me :P